# Applied class attribute to <thead> fails to apply ckeditor 4

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor4.x

I've been able to apply CSS classes to other ckeditor.styles.js in my Drupal 7 theme using the ckeditor module. 
But customer wants option to style a table header a certain way. Looking at the html produced by this library I see that the  cells are all wrapped by a single  tag. Great, If my customer wants to style the header row in this way this ought to work:

```
{ name : 'Gray head',     element : 'thead', attributes : { 'class' : 'foo'} },
```

And the CSS shows:

```
div.responsive-table table thead.foo {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1pt;
    background: rgba(168,157,157,1.00);
  }
```

The table is set with a header to "first row". And after setting this initial table to "condensed table" and then right-clicking a cell in the first row to select "Gray head" I find that the attribute is not being applied to the parent  element, but instead there are empty  elements created for each column. I've tried different combinations of describing the selectors but am failing to apply a class attribute to this parent  element. Thx, sam